# Sendmail Hostname error

Tags: centos, fedora, postfix, hostname, sendmail

We recently changed hostname on our Fedora server to `xyz`

and Sendmail logs report like: `July 08 00:06:36 xyz sendmail[20506]:`

That's fine. But we changed the hostname back to `abc` but the sendmail still thinks xyz is the correct hostname. Any fix for this?

Comment: Did you restart the send mail service after changing the hostname?

Comment: Also restart the syslog daemon.